# vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)

Tags: c++, vector

I am stuck in a loop with vector. Any comments will be appreciated!  Below shows my code. here I show only 2 vectors,each with one elements to explain my question. if I need , for example, 8 vectors(each vector has 10 elements), how should i do to avoid overflow. Thanks a lot!

The error is:

> "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>     what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)
>   Aborted (core dumped)

main code:

```
    const int dR(1),effm(1);
    std::vector<double>  DR_l1j({0});
    std::vector<double>  M_eff({200});


    void Loop()
    {
        //main loop
        for (Long64_t jentry=0; jentry<10000;jentry++)
        {

                //loop
                for(int i = 0; i < dR; i++){
                        if(dRl1j > DR_l1j.at(i)){
                                for(int j = 0; j < effm ; j++){
                                        if(meff > M_eff.at(j)*1000){
                                          (some calculation)      ;
             }
           }
         }                                                                                               
        int main()
         {loop()；return 0;}
```

Comment: Catch the exception in a debugger to see when and where in your code it happens, and what index you use for the vector. And `out_of_range` should kind of give you a hint about the problem.

Comment: Also that code is really nasty and very hard to read. Anything more than two or possibly three levels of nesting makes the code hard to read, understand and maintain. And considering the dimensions and sizes of the vectors you show, much of that isn't really needed for a [mcve]. Why have a loop that will only iterate once?